# How to start an activity which is defined in different package from a widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget with a clickable Imageview. When i click on the widget, I want it to launch an activity which is in different package. But I am not getting any errors and the click event is not happening also. I am giving my code below.

```
Intent start = new Intent(context, com.abc.xyz.Start.class);//com.abc.xyz->other package        
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 0, start, 0);          
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.widget_main);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.clickable_image_widget, pendingIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

its not ideal to start an application directly through package name/classname.

Comment: i want to know whether it matters that the activity is in same package or different package?

Comment: So how can I do that? Any idea..? Can u please edit the code in the right way?